# Can't get rid of Mediawiki InstantCommon Images

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki at http://spider.dnsdojo.net running on LAMP.  I enabled the use of InstantCommons while trying to setup the UploadWizard extension.  Ever since I can't get at least one of my images to show up correctly.  It keeps showing the InstantComons image even though I have disabled the use of InstantCommons.

-So far I've

- cleared the cache and cookies on chrome
- purged the site using index.php?title=3x3x3_LED_Cube&action=purge
- delete all images and re-upload

It's driving me crazy, because when I click on the image it takes me to the file page which shows the correct jpg.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is a MediaWiki bug or if I was just doing something wrong, but I finally got the proper image showing up.  What finally did it, I think, was uploading the image and then uploading it again over top of itself.  Maybe this will save someone else a few hours of frustration.